# CultureInfo in Metadata - MVC ASP.NET - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, label, metadata, cultureinfo

I need set a cultureinfo different of others in a currency field.

Metadata:

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Expressions), Name = "PriceInEuro")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "TheFieldXIsRequired")]
    public double PriceInEuro { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    <div>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteEntity.Price)
       <span class="display">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.QuoteEntity.Price, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))        </span>
    </div>
```

My application have a CultureInfo US (en-US) as default, but this field should be displayed in REAL format (pt-BR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a new property on the model?

```
public string PriceInReal
{
    get
    {
         CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR");
         return String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", Price);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I need format this model, because this metadata is based on a Entity (edmx).

Comment: @GuilhermeManeskul could you pass the Entity into the model as another constructor? That would be a better way of doing it

Comment: This is a patch, not a solution.

Comment: @MauricioUlloa it's the only way of doing it without using a client side solution